# Crash fetching row value for custom type

Tags: macos, sqlite.swift

I've defined an enum and made it conform to `Value` like so:

```
enum Name: Int {
    //cases
}

extension Name: Value {
    static var declaredDatatype: String {
        return Int.declaredDatatype
    }
    static func fromDatatypeValue(_ intValue: Int) -> Name {
        return Name(rawValue: intValue)!
    }
    var datatypeValue: Int {
        return self.rawValue
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I get the follow exception:
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

It happens in this function:

```
public func get<V: Value>(_ column: Expression<V>) -> V {
    return get(Expression<V?>(column))!
}
```

The function in my enum extension is not called so I think this is a more general bug in SQLite.swift, but it only happens with my custom type.

Im using Xcode 8.3.3 and SQLite.swift ec7b589.

Comment: Instead of using `!` to force unwrap things, test them using `if let` so that you can break in the debugger (or print information) to find out what caused the unexpected value.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'l try to dig a bit deeper.

Comment: I found that when I matched my custom type to Int64 it all works. So it seems the documentation is wrong, because the example with the `Date` matches to an Int, but it only works with Int64. It's this line that returns nil: `guard let value = values[idx] as? V.Datatype else { return nil }` (line 1050 in Query.Swift)